# How to Write a WMI Provider in C#.NET 4.0?

Tags: c#-4.0

Can any help me to write a WMI Provider for Battery using C#.net 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an old C# example [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/falkor/wmiproviderguide11262005021524am/wmiproviderguide.aspx). Maybe you can use that as a starting point.