# Windows Management Infrastructure Provider in C#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to create a Windows MI provider in C#? All the sample code I have found so far is in C. There is sample code for MI clients in C#, but not providers. If anyone has a link to any samples or discussions on how to do this, I would be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

A Google search for "wmi in c# examples" produced this:

[Sample C# code for using the latest WMI classes to manage Windows Storage](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2014/08/11/sample-c-code-for-using-the-latest-wmi-classes-to-manage-windows-storage/)

It may be worth a scan to see if it gives you the clues you require.

Edit:

Sorry, you said providers... curses!

[I should have pointed you to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041296/how-to-write-a-wmi-provider-in-c-net-4-0)

Apologies.

BTW, that came from googling "wmi providers in c# examples" so I don't understand why you didn't find it.

Comment: I didn't find it because this is not what I am looking for. This is a WMI sample. Windows Management Instrumentation. What I am looking for is information on the new APIs, for Windows Management Infrastructure. One is WMI, and the other is Windows MI. Leave it to Microsoft to make two stacks that do the same thing, and have the same acronym. It makes finding information on it harder. For example: http://www.smartazure.com/blogs/wmi-client-in-c-with-the-mi-net-api/

Comment: Based on further reading, it looks like MI providers are C only, and that the Windows MI C# API is client only. This makes the original question unanswerable.

Comment: Oh man, why on earth didn't they call it something else?!?!? Sorry for the confusion, I was having a quick look before going out for the evening.